# Fading in elements when they reaching the middle of page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I would like to "fade in" once that element is in the middle 60% of the page.

Whilst within the top 20% and bottom 20% of the page, it should have an opacity of 20%(0.2).Then when it falls within the middle 60% it should have 100% opacity

This is what I have got to, and tried a few different thing but nothing seems to work.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="timeline_item">
  <div class="timeline_left">
    <div class="timeline_date-text">
      2009
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.timeline_item{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        transition: opacity 2s; 
    }
```

And my JS:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline_item');

const startAnimation = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const element = entry.target;
    const middleOfPage = window.innerHeight / 2;
    const top20vh = window.innerHeight * 0.2;
    const bottom20vh = window.innerHeight * 0.8;

    if (entry.boundingClientRect.top < top20vh) {
        // Element in the top 20vh
        element.style.opacity = '0.2';
    } else if (entry.boundingClientRect.bottom > bottom20vh) {
        // Element in the bottom 20vh
        element.style.opacity = '0.2';
    } else {
        // Element in the middle 60vh
        element.style.opacity = '1';
    }
});
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(startAnimation, { threshold: 0 });
 elements.forEach(el => {
    observer.observe(el);
});
```

The problem I am having is that the element always has the 20% opacity, and never detects when the element is within the 60% range even when in the center of the page:

[image]

Any help would be amazing thanks

Comment: Have a look at what threshold 0 means. You are getting a notification when the element gets into or out of the window only.